# HashMap versus Object ? Which one is better to finally generate JSON output with KEY and VALUE

Tags: json, enums, hashmap

I do have this use case.

1. callers(APIs in same microservice or different microservices) wants to report different KEYS and VALUES as an audit as part of their methods.
2. There is a high possibilities that some of KEYS will be very common that majority of callers can report.
3. consistency is MUST when using KEY NAME from multiple callers to report same KEY. Example: if all wants to report consumer ID, then all callers need to use key "consumerId" only to bring consistency across different callers.
4. Can have some reusable enum class to hold all common keys like above so that every callers can use. Callers can still have their own custom KEYS which they want to report.
5. All callers should not do a duplicate jobs like if caller1, caller2 wants to report consumerID (common KEY), then I dont want both to define class with consumerID as property and then convert that into JSON.

I thought to use below kind of implementation.

**Enum to hold common KEYS**

```
public enum EnumKeys implements Key {
CONSUMERID("consumerId")
...
...
...
}
```

**Common class each caller can use to report KEY AND VALUE**
    @JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic=true)
    public class ReportData {

```
private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

public ReportData add(Key key, Object value){
    properties.put(key.getKeyName(), value);
    return this;
}
```

**Caller 1 Reporting consumerID**

```
ReportData reportData = new ReportData();
reportData.add(EnumKeys.CONSUMERID,"123");
```

**Caller 2 Reporting consumerID**

ReportData reportData = new ReportData(); 
   reportData.add(EnumKeys.CONSUMERID,"435");

**Caller 3 Reporting XYZ key which is not common**

```
//First create a custom KEY
public enum CustomEnum implements Key{

XYZ("xyz");
}

ReportData reportData = new ReportData();
reportData.add(CustomEnum.XYZ,"custom value");
```

Finally framework will convert each property key pair to JSON

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(reportData);
```

**Output**

1. Not all callers needs to create holder class (equivalent to ReportData) to hold properties.
2. Using instance of ReportData, they can bring consistency on using same KEY name for KEY
3. Callers can extend EnumKeys (master list of KEYs) and define their own keys and still can use same way of reporting.

**Questions**

1. Is there anything bad about this way of usage?
2. Anything bad to instantiate object (ReportData) out of HashMap/EnumMap?
3. Is object (with instance members) better to generate JSON or HASHMAP with more constrained KEY NAME is better? Final destination is JSON.
4. Any easy way to use existing class (with n of properties) and use with ReportData class.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know data structure up front I would definitely go for object approach as it gives you type  safety on the key value pairs.

With the hashmap things can be more dynamic but you will lose type safety.

Think string vs int vs float vs bool in json and how to use the hashmap vs the object in code.

Think readability vs flexibility vs need for casting.

Comment: `Think string vs int vs float vs bool in json ` that's part of the question I'm implying.

Comment: I know data structure and few keys (like platform keys) which I can enforce all to use same key but I dont know what will be extended keys (user defined keys) and I am trying to find how can I enforce integrity /consistency when they define and use keys